# Programmatically Scrolling is not working C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

i have one panel and i put a flow layout panel in the main panel and flow layout panel has many images. my UI looks like this
[image]

now i got a code which scroll the container in the panel. i mean the flow layout will scroll in main panel when i will place my mouse at the left or right most area on the main panel. their code is working i checked but when i place their code in my project then that is not working, i means scrolling is not working when i place my mouse at the left or right most area on the main panel.

here i am attaching main code which causes to scroll the flow layout panel inside in main panel

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
                return cp;
            }
        } 
         int _myval = 5;
        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);

            if (e.Y < metroPanel1.Top || e.Y > metroPanel1.Top + metroPanel1.Height) return;

            if (e.X <= metroPanel1.Left && e.X >= metroPanel1.Left - 40)
            {
                if (metroPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Value <= _myval)
                {
                    metroPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = _myval;
                }
                else
                {
                    metroPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Value -= _myval;
                }
            }

            if (e.X <= (metroPanel1.Left + metroPanel1.Width + 40)   && e.X >= (metroPanel1.Left + metroPanel1.Width))
            {
                metroPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Value += _myval;
            }
        }
```

i just do not understand this value 40 used here `if (e.X <= metroPanel1.Left && e.X >= metroPanel1.Left - 40)`

i guess i need to use different value rather than 40 but i used 10 & 20 but did not work.
here is my full project link from where anyone can download and see what is wrong in my routine which prevent the scrolling. here is the link **https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=C4A6F16F34D7540A&resid=C4A6F16F34D7540A%21134&authkey=AM5Fq2gcFLtcw_A**

so it is my request that please some one see my code and guide me what i need to change in code and why. thanks

Comment: It looks like that 40 is just padding to allow you a gap to see if the mouse is near the edge rather than exactly at the edge, if anything you would be better increasing this value (during testing)

Comment: how do i detect what value i should give like 40 or 60....just by trail & error? is there any short cut way to know what value i should use? thanks

Comment: Thats basically it, its trial and error for the most part, 40 pixels does sounds big enough to me but its what suits you

Comment: i test with 60 & 80 too but still no luck.

Comment: Thats probably not the issue, just set a breakpoint inside one of the if conditions and see if it is hit, if so, what happens. Your question is possibly too broad for so

Comment: basically i need to detect mouse touch the main panel left most edge or right most edge programmatically but i have no idea how to achieve it programmatically. can u help....thanks

Comment: I really doubt that there is a way to get a FLP to scoll when the scrollbars aren't there. try to put cone in a scroll button to verify this. If you knew how to scroll, you can use the mouse detection code of my answer, but I'd be surprised (and delighted) if real scrolling is possible..

Comment: See my answer for the question of 'how to scroll programmatically (without visible scrollbars)' As to your project: I have d'loaded it and will have a look, but atm I'm rather tired.. I made a few nice improvements&corrections to the mouseSroller btw, will upload later or tomorrow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Yes, programmatically scrolling a `FlowLayoutPanel` is **not working**, if the `Scrollbars` are not shown, due to its `AutoScroll`  being off.

Neither setting `HorizontalScroll.Value` (in any way) nor using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar, int nPos, bool bRedraw);
```

will do anything.

Not even doing this has any effect:

```
flowLayoutPanel1ScrollControlIntoView(someControlThatsOutOfSight);
```

So, as far as I can tell: Without active Scrollbar(s) no scrolling a `FlowLayoutPanel`!

The containing `Panel` can however indeed be scrolled the way valter shows. However my first tests showed even when using a double-buffered Panel subclass a terrible flicker..

**Update:**

I can't get the Panel to scroll reliably. I have checked up on the link and found that the behaviour is really much simpler than anything I had written: No up down scrolling, no edge detection, no speed detection, no direction detection. In fact there are two scroll zones and when the mouse is in one, it scrolls.. It also relies on the 'constant firing of the mousemove event bug', which only works for me when I don't want it..!

So, here is a solution that implements this behaviour and is, of course much shorter, than the original code.

I include a screenshot to show you the layout: You need two Panels and the FlowLayoutPanel.
The outer Panel is a little wider so that its right and left part work as the scroll zones.
The inner Panel contains the FLP; the FLP has AutoSize=true.

There is a timer scrollTimer with a fast Intervall of 5-10ms.

[image: layout]

Here is the code:

```
int speed = 10;
int delta = 0;

private void panOuter_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    delta = e.X < panOuter.Width / 2 ? speed : -speed;
    scrollTimer.Start();
}

private void panOuter_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scrollTimer.Stop();
}

private void scrollTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int newLeft = FLP.Left + delta;
    int alpha = panInner.ClientRectangle.Width - FLP.ClientRectangle.Width;

    if (newLeft > 0) { newLeft = 0; scrollTimer.Stop(); }
    else if (  newLeft <  alpha)
    { newLeft = alpha; scrollTimer.Stop(); }

    FLP.Left = newLeft;
}
```

That's practically all you need. Only in case you Dock or Anchor the outer Panel you should script the Resize event to keep the inner Panel centered!

Comment: thanks for answer. u said "I made a few nice improvements&corrections to the mouseSroller btw, will upload later or tomorrow" so please give me the link by which i can download your improved version of scrolling project. thanks

Comment: Hey, before I'll finalize my class I have started to wonder about one detail: Just when should the scrolling begin? The cursor must be near enough, that is clear. But what about its movement? Is it ok to start scrolling while still moving? (Which is what I have now..) Or should it start when the cursor stand for a little while in the scroll zone? Or only if the movement is not too fast..?? - The problem is: I think it should be possible to __move the cursor out__ of the FLP / form.. __without__
 starting a scroll!

Comment: here i am giving a link which let u download a sample winform project.https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=C4A6F16F34D7540A&resid=C4A6F16F34D7540A%21133&authkey=AC-BXcngO7n2g9Q  just develop something similar. but use only built-in panel & FLP to develop your UI. the link was good....just see it u will be happy.

Comment: checked out the code and wrote a simple impementation.. just a dozen lines of code ;-)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can u plzz upload your source code in zip format.

Comment: i have gave link here like metro style scrolling. If u see that code then u may notice smooth scrolling can be done with mimum code. Just can be done changing panel horizental scroll bar value. I used that trick but mine didnt work.

Comment: Well, as I have told you repeatedly this doesn't work because a `FlowLayoutPanel` (or a `Panel` for that matter) is not a `MetroPanel`. Also: the code there is hardly shorter than the 11 lines above!

Comment: Here u said it is not possible but u provide a new ui and code. Does ur new code help me to achieve my goal?

Comment: of course it does. what is __not__ possible to __literally scroll a flowlayoutpanel__ . instead I position it inside the innerPanel..

Comment: So i will test ur code and let u know. Thanks and have nice weekend @Taw.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to scroll dont use

```
metroPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Value -= _myval;
or
metroPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Value += _myval;
```

but instead

```
_myval -= 5;
or _myval += 5;
metroPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = _myval;
metroPanel1.Refresh();
```

valter

Comment: Sorry for my comments - yes, this does make a difference and it does scroll a Panel even without visible scrollbars! I was applying it to the FLP, which does not scroll in any way at all..Time to go to sleep, tomorrow I'll see if changing the mouse scrolling code does make things easier.. probably can save the stop code..

Comment: i like to request u plzz download my sample project from this link https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=C4A6F16F34D7540A&resid=C4A6F16F34D7540A%21134&authkey=AM5Fq2gcFLtcw_A and do all the necessary changes to get the scrolling work. i follow your code but still no luck. thanks

Comment: @Thomas It works out of the box. It flickers and the movement is kinda choppy but works.

Comment: the sample link i gave u is not scrolling fully. please check and if possible make this apps perfect. thanks

Comment: @Thomas Sorry but i haven't work with metro framework. If it were regular controls then i could do that.

Comment: i am not talking about metro framework rather my win apps. this is link https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=C4A6F16F34D7540A&resid=C4A6F16F34D7540A%21134&authkey=AM5Fq2gcFLtcw_A from where u can download my solution and see why scrolling is not working. in this project i used normal panel and flow layout panel. if u have time then please have a look and guide me how to get the scrolling work.

Comment: @Thomas Ah. I see. The way i would do it(for smoothness and speed) is draw every image in an offscreen one and then draw part of it in a timer simulating scrolling. Even better using GDI. You dont have to use 20+ controls. If it is ok i will give the code.

Comment: ok give me the code in downloadable format in zip file so i can run and see how u like to solve it. thanks

Comment: This is also an intersting way to tackle the issue! @Thomas: Please tell valter (and me) about the dynamics of the FLP!! Do the contents change? How and how often? Are they like live tiles or is there scrolling inside the PictureBoxes etc..

Comment: On second thought I wonder how the nested controls will still be reactive..? Curious to hear about your progress!

Comment: @Thomas The problem(choppy movement) is not actuall the speed but to draw at the exact refresh rate of screen. This can be accomplished **only** with directx. The code is very easy but you need the managed directx library or SharpDX.

Comment: @Thomas You can download the file [here](http://www.filedropper.com/mdi) Try it to see if it is ok. It uses directx

Comment: I see it scroll fine. Are these active pictureboxes when I'm over them?

Comment: @TaW When you are scrolling no (visible = false). When the scrolling stops (visible = true)

Comment: @TaW Can post a link to your executable to check it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61583/discussion-between-taw-and-valter).

Comment: @ γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε : i try to download the file but my norton symantec removed that file after download. if possible please zip that file and then upload. if possible upload whole project so we can see the code.

Comment: @Thomas [code](http://pastebin.com/mCk6b4Sw) and file [file](http://www.filedropper.com/scrollwithdirectx)

Comment: i try to run your exe called scrollWithDirectX but could not run. can't u upload your whole project source code in zip format? why you are uploading exe file? no body trust to dowload & run your exe. if possible upload ur full project in zip format. thanks

Comment: i check the code that was in vb.net.....it would be much better if u write in c#. thanks

Comment: @Thomas Do you have directX references? I mean, can you use dierectX?

Comment: directx was installed in my pc. if possible please upload your whole project in zip file so i can open the project in my pc & run. did u write the program in c# or vb.net ?